# How to disable inline headphone controls on Windows 10/11

Tags: windows-10, audio, windows-11, headphones, headphone-jack

I have a pair of (3.5mm) headphones that work fine but send erroneous headphone control signals (i.e. raising and lowering the volume, skipping/pausing). Personally, I never use inline headphone controls anyway.

I'm pretty sure there isn't any official way to disable inline headphone controls on Windows, but is there a registry hack, or an external program that could do the same thing? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a driver update for the headphones?   Try this Microsoft article for fixes.  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-not-detecting-any-headphones-and/c4278c0f-c657-474e-8895-a7138c62d632

Comment: What are your headphones?